# How to force values for second level of multi index?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    list('aabbaaa'),
    list('efghefg')
], names=['one', 'two'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': "val"}, mux)
print(df)
```

gives

```
         col
one two     
a   e    val
    f    val
b   g    val
    h    val
a   e    val
    f    val
    g    val
         col
```

I want to set all values of the second multi index level "two" to values of my choosing, in this case, to `np.arange(start=1, stop=len(df) + 1)`

My attempt

```
df.index.set_levels(levels=np.arange(start=1, stop=len(df)+1), level=1, inplace=True) 
print(df)
```

gives

```
one two     
a   1    val
    2    val
b   3    val
    4    val
a   1    val
    2    val
    3    val
```

instead of

```
one two     
a   1    val
    2    val
b   3    val
    4    val
a   5    val
    6    val
    7    val
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need recreate `MultiIndex`, because `set_levels` only set by unique values of level, so in your solution are replaced only 4 values of second level:

```
print(df.index.levels)
[['a', 'b'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]


a = df.index.get_level_values(0)
b = np.arange(start=1, stop=len(df)+1)

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a, b], names=['one','two'])
print (df)
         col
one two     
a   1    val
    2    val
b   3    val
    4    val
a   5    val
    6    val
    7    val
```

Another idea:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1).assign(two = b).set_index('two', append=True)
print (df)
         col
one two     
a   1    val
    2    val
b   3    val
    4    val
a   5    val
    6    val
    7    val
```